# ios 7 customizing UITableViewCell's content view

Tags: uitableview, storyboard, ios7, xcode5

Using storyboard in **ios7** the content view is explicitly viewed under the **Table View Cell** in the story board editor (opposed to previous versions where it was hidden from the interface).

The problem is that I cannot connect the cell's custom elements to my custom cell's ib outlets anymore (subclass of `UITableCellView`) and can only connect them to the table's content view (`UIView`) which CANNOT be customized (i.e. its custom class attribute is grayed)

This leaves me with the option to use tags which I find inconvenient and less elegant.

I could also create a custom view in a xib, do all the connections and then manually add this custom view as the content view of the table but I am looking for a way doing it via the story board editor.

Is there a way to connect UI elements to a custom cell's content view in the story board editor in ios7 ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to do this by doing the following:

1. Select the cell in the document outline
2. Change its custom class in the Identity Inspector
3. Place whatever elements you want into the content view
4. Connect the IBOutlets to the elements inside the content view using the Connections Inspector

Comment: How did you made the connections ? Where are the IBOutlets are declared ? mind that the view controller is not a solution here for dynamic cells as each cell is copied when created

Comment: I have a custom subclass of UITableViewCell and declared outlets on that object.

Comment: Yep me too. Can you change the custom class of the content view ?

Comment: and the Oscar goes to .... Apparently the way to connect them is doing the 4 step in your answer which seemed odd enough as this should also have worked by ctrl+dragging the elements to the custom cell class. Anyway that does the job. Thanks !

Comment: I'm not sure about changing the contentView, but I believe the answer is no. You also can't change it in code as that property is readonly. I generally stick to custom UITableViewCells. I think of them as the view controllers for the cell views.

Comment: I knew about customizing the cell but from previous versions ctrl+drag should have worked. Anyway it works as you described so the job is done :)

Answer (score 17):

Ok I found an Xcode bug.

If you complete the following this will replicate the issue: 
- Create new UIViewController in storyboard
- Drag a UITableView to the VC
- Update the UITableview to have 1(as many) dynamic prototype cells
ISSUE: The cells are added but without a contentView.

RESOLUTION:
Rather than updating the amount of cells in the storyboard. 
Drag a custom cell from the objects part of Xcode, the Cell will be added with a contentView.

Comment: Hi StuartM, I have no problem adding a custom cell to the table view. My problem is that the contentView of the custom cell cannot be customized so I cannot connect UI elements to the custom cell to be used naturally when I fetch the cell

Comment: Read my comment, let me know if I didn't understood your  answer correctly.

Comment: Yes, I presume you cannot see the contentView to therefore add UI Elements to the custom cell.

Comment: On the contrary, the content view is shown, the thing is its "custom class" attribute is gray so I cannot create a custom view and connect the element to its outlets

Comment: Are you sure you are selecting the cell when trying to set the custom class. If you select the contentView you will not be able to change the custom class of that.

Comment: Yes, I created a custom cell class and changed the class attribute of the cell to my custom class but still I cannot drag anything into it, only into the contentView

Comment: I am confused? You should only be able to drag into the contentView. Are you saying that is what you can do or cannot do? If you cannot, is this because you do not have a contentView - if so, see the answer.

Comment: I can drag elements into the contentView but since I cannot set its custom class then I cannot connect the elements to the IBOutlets of the custom class.

Comment: I've run into this today. Thanks for the fix StuartM. Have you filed a radar?

Comment: Yes sir, (Duplicate of 14866276 (Open)). Feel free to file one too and note that it is a duplicate of that number. The more reports the quicker it is likely to be resolved. Feel free to vote the answer up too for visibility

Answer (score 1):

I don't really know the answer, but I can suggest work around this issue:

1) Copy existing cell from other tableview to the one you're working on.

2) You will have contentView under your cell now. Design this cell by adding your views.

3) Create a class for your cell, e.g NewCell, then manually create IBOutlet in this class:

`@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel* mainLabel;`

4) Assign the cell class in storyboard to the class you just created. After this step, you can drag the  outlet from storyboard to class.

I'm not sure if this is a bug for XCode 5 or it is intended, and I'm looking for better solutions as well.

Comment: Stumbled across this strange issue too. If anyone does have any other suggestions please note them

Comment: Well, if I try to connect the label to the custom cell class in IB I don't get any options (properties to connecto to). The cell is not even highlighted when I ctrl+drag the label to the custom cell class in IB. I can only drag it to the cell's content view which does not help as it cannot be customized

Comment: See answer below, this is the resolution. There is a bug with Xcode I filed a Radar.

Comment: For me, when I have a contentView in cell, I just drag my labels to it (make sure that these labels are inside contentView, not outside). By setting the cell class to ```NewCell```, I can just control-drag from the label to the ```NewCell.h```and set the IBOutlet there. If it didn't work for you, how about trying to restart Xcode?

Answer (score 0):

Create new uiviewcontroller with xib interface and add the required sub-views .Also,establish the iboutlet connections.

Now ,rename the viewcontroller : UIViewcontroller to viewcontroller : UITableviewcell in .h file of your newly created view controller.

Your tableviewcell was created and ready to use with any UITableview of any class.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I might be duplicating someone else's answer but I found this workaround which helped bypass this silly XCode bug. Short solution: When you build your custom cell in Storyboard, do NOT drag your UI elements inside the cell or content view.

Instead, drag them OUTSIDE so that they're child elements of the parent table view!

It's easiest to do this drag and drop if you use the little hierarchy menu on the left to make sure your elements wind up in the right spot.

Once the elements are dragged in, just control-click and drag from the custom cell to the UI elements to make your connections. Woo hoo!

Once your connections are set, then (finally) drag the UI elements back INTO the custom cell's content view and lay them out as you normally would.

UPDATE: While my method works, look for a comment by thomasdao in an answer below where he just drags the connections directly into the .h file (the little circles in the left margin where you declare your IBOutlets) -- this is actually the easiest solution but unfortunately it's stuck as a comment.